# In triangle ABC, find the range of sinAsinC.

Tags: trigonometry

In $\triangle$ABC, $\angle$B=$\frac{\pi}{3}$. Find the range of sinAsinC.

I used C=120-A to  simplify the equation in sinC and then applied $-1<sinC<1$ but answer did not matched.

Comment: $\sin C$ must be positive for the range $C\in(0,\pi)$.

Comment: $sinC$ is negative for $C \in(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})$

Comment: Wolfram alpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+sin(x)sin(y)+where+x%2by+%3d+2%2f3*pi&incParTime=true) says the maximum is around $\frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From given, $A+C = \frac{2\pi}3$.
$$\sin A\sin C = \frac{\cos(A-C)-\cos(A+C)}{2} = \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi}3-2C)-\cos\frac{2\pi}3}{2}$$
Find the maximum and the minimum of the first $\cos$ term.

---

For maximum, choose $C = \frac\pi3$, which gives $\cos(\frac{2\pi}3-2C) = 1$.

For minimum, choose $C = 0$ or $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, which gives $\cos(\frac{2\pi}3-2C) = -\frac12$.

$$0 =\frac{-1/2+1/2}{2} < \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi}3-2C)-\cos\frac{2\pi}3}{2} \le \frac{1+1/2}2 = \frac34$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin A\sin C=\sin A\sin(2\pi/3-A)=\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin A\cos A+\frac12\sin^2A$$

Now define
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin x\cos x+\frac12\sin^2x=\frac{\sqrt3}4\sin2x+\frac14(1-\cos2x)$$
for $x\in(0,2\pi/3)$.

The derivative of $f$ is
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos2x+\frac12\sin2x=\frac1{2\cos2x}(\sqrt3+\tan2x)$$

This is $0$ when $\tan 2x=-\sqrt3$, that is, when $x=\pi/3$.

Now, $f(\pi/3)=3/8+3/8=3/4$. Since this is a maximum (can you check that?), the range of $f$ is $(0,3/4]$.